# REST API naming convention

Tags: api, rest, naming

Given this URI:

```
/myapp/books/status/{status}
```

For example :

```
/myapp/books/status/new
```

This will return all books flagged with this status.

What would be a proper URI for return all books NOT flagged with a specific status?

```
/myapp/books/notstatus/new
```

I would like to return a collection of all books except the ones with a certain status..

Please advice...

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend using query parameters for filtering status for your books list resource:

```
myapp/books/?status=new
myapp/books/?status=not_new
```

Both queries return the same resource (a list of books), you're just filtering out the types you want in that list, so the use of a query param makes sense.  I use the `not_` prefixed to the status to do inverse queries, but you can use whatever convention you want.

REST doesn't require you to avoid get parameters (it seems some people think get parameters are voodoo), just don't use them to make faux-RPC calls :)

The reason I like this method is it opens up your options later  when you might want to add a check for all books with multiple pieces of info such as ones that have a status of new and condition of good.

```
    myapp/books/?status=new&condition=good
```

If you try to break that down into url segments instead of query params, it gets messy very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

As I know there are a couple of ways, and all of them are correct (from REST perspective):

- Query string parameters

> myapp/books?status=new

- OData queries
  http://www.odata.org/documentation/uri-conventions

> myapp/books?$filter=status eq 'new'

- In URI, also good

> myapp/books/status/{status}

Personally I prefer either Query string or OData.

OData is especially good when technology specific (ASP.NET Web API, WCF Data services, by non-Microsofts should also be equivalents) helps to avoid writing any code for such queries.

It allows to expose prefiltered collection and then filter it from client with such query. In such scenarios when exposing collections, I'm using OData queries.